# Как правильно отправить код своего приложения другому для просмотра багов?

Tags: android-studio

Как правильно отправить код своего приложения другому для просмотра багов? К примеру тут.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Это вопрос больше подходит для Мета ru SO

Comment: Дать ссылку на репозиторий (github, bitbucket). И, конечно, к нему должен быть открыт доступ.